# Unable to click on an element after switching to frame in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am unable to click on an element after switching the focus to the correct frame. The frame does not have name/id attributes. Switching to frame was ok, but 'TimeoutException' was given when I added click command.
I have tried various ways:

1. Explicit wait
2. Tried different XPATHs
3. submit() instead of click()
4. send_keys(Keys.RETURN) instead of click()
5. Used ActionChains class to move to element and click on it

Comment: Post the url you are accessing.

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML of the frame & the element along with your code trials.